# sweetalert not working on django template

Tags: django, sweetalert

I started with the following code to send the ID to a method to delete an object of model.But the first ID is always sent.

this is my HTML and JavaScript code:

```
{% for yad in yads %}
  <form action="{% url 'del-yadd' %}" method="post" id="myform">
      {% csrf_token %}
      <button type="button" name="yidd" value="{{yad.id}}" id="btndelme"  class=" btn btn-danger" onclick="
   swal({
          title: 'warning!',
          text: 'do you want to delete?',
          type: 'warning',
          showCancelButton: true,
          confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
          cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
          cancelButtonText:'no',
          confirmButtonText: 'yes'
         },
         function(isConfirm) {
          if (isConfirm) {
             document.querySelector('#myform').submit();
            }});   
">delete</button> 
    
  </form>
{% endfor %}
```

and this is my Django view code:
def delete_yadd(request):
id=request.POST['yidd']
yad=Yadd.objects.filter(id=id).delete()
return redirect('home')

Comment: so my django views code It does not have a good format on this post

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your **SweetAlert is not showing** is because it needs to be called right near the end of the html document by using a javascript function. Things I have changed are the way you call the sweetalert function like below:

```
{% for yad in yads %}
<form action="{% url 'del-yadd' %}" method="post" id="myform">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <button type="button" name="yidd" value="{{yad.id}}" id="btndelme"  class=" btn btn-danger" onclick="confirm()"></button>
</form>
{% endfor %}
<script>
    function confirm() {
        swal({
                title: 'warning!',
                text: 'do you want to delete?',
                icon: 'warning',
                showCancelButton: true,
                confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
                cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
                cancelButtonText: 'no',
                confirmButtonText: 'yes'
            },
            function (isConfirm) {
                if (isConfirm) {
                    document.querySelector('#myform').submit();
                }
            })
    }
</script>
```